# Why does this function never go beyond the first line?

Tags: c++

I am reading the Bjarne Stroustrup's book, which is very confusing for me (probably because English is not my first language). This book says expression() will never go beyond the first line of code. Does the fact that expression() starts by calling itself cause expression() to call itself infinitely? How does this work?
Thanks.

```
double expression()
{
    double left = expression();
    Token t = get_token();
    swich(t.kind) {
        case'+':
            return left + term();
        case'-':
            return left - term();
        default:
            return left;
    }
}
```

Comment: It recursively calls itself, forever. `double left = expression();` - this invokes the `expression` method immediately when `expression` is called.

Comment: It will eventually crash due to stack overflow. What exactly is the question?

Comment: See [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

Comment: 10 GOSUB 10 : REM equivalent code

Comment: Recursive function calls (like the line double left = expression();) should always go inside if statements so that the recursion can be stopped once a certain condition is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding recursive function calls first requires understanding function calls. See the following short example:

```
void print() {
   std::cout << "Hello! ";
}

int main() {
   print();
   print();
}
```

Output will be `Hello! Hello!`, since function `main` calls function `print` two times, and the program will end then.

Now consider what happens if function `print` contains a call `print()`, i.e. if it calls "itself":

```
void print() {
   std::cout << "Hello! ";
   print();
}
```

Then, the output will be an (almost) endless sequence of `Hello! Hello! Hello!...`, since - after having printed out one `Hello!`, function print calls itself, and the same procedure happens again and again.

Hope it helps. And BTW: You'd probably  start  with a different book :-)

Comment: Thanks. Which book should I read? I want to finish this book.  :(

Comment: @zen Stroustrup has written a number of books. If the book is *Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++*, it really is hard to do much better for early learning. His other books tend to be focused less on learning the language and more on the design and details  of C++.

Comment: Thanks. I will continue to finish this book. And I will keep going to ask questions if I do not understand. Hope you guys help me.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's an endless loop, read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop

```
double expression()
{
    double left = expression(); // <-- Each time the program reaches this line, it calls expression() again.
    (...)
}
```